# How to get either select .val() or div .text() from dynamically created elements with same id?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Depending on the user type, my page dynamically creates either a select element (for admins to change) or a div with text (for regular users) using the same id.

```
if ($user_type == 'admin') {
    echo "<tr><td>Type:</td><td><select id='type' >";
    echo "<option value='student' >student</option><option value='teacher' >teacher</option>";
    echo "</select></td></tr>";
}
else echo "<tr><td>Type:</td><td><div id='type'>" . $user_type . "</div></td></tr>";
```

When the page submits, I need either the .val() from the select element or the .text() from the div element.

I can't use .val() on the div element and I can't use .text() on the select element.

Is there a way in jQuery / javascript to get one or the other, depending on which element type was created?

Comment: One easy way to do it would be to create a hidden input field in the case that you create the div.  Give the hidden field the same id and the value you want.  And then in both cases `val()` would apply.

Comment: The DOM offers you the `nodeName` property on elements that will be 'DIV' or 'SELECT' in this case, so you can chose the correct logic.

Answer (score 0):

make the else statement as so (use input[type=hidden], to use the .val())

```
else echo
"<tr>
  <td>Type:</td>
  <td>
    <!-- div to show the value -->
    <div>$user_type</div>
    <!-- hidden input type to get the value via jQuery .val() -->
    <input type='hidden' id='type' value='$user_type'>
  </td>
</tr>";
```

Oh by the way, you can use PHP variables inside strings that are defined with double quotes `echo "$someVar";`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are printing out from PHP the HTML out put, by the same time you can print a Javascript variable who has what method use to get the value/text. Then, use the variable in your Javascript to perform one query or other.

Something like :

```
if ($user_type == 'admin') {
    echo "<tr><td>Type:</td><td><select id='type' >";
    echo "<option value='student' >student</option><option value='teacher'>teacher</option>";
    echo "</select></td></tr>";
    echo "<script> var method = 'val'</script>";
}
else 
{ 
    echo "<tr><td>Type:</td><td><div id='type'>" . $user_type . "</div></td></tr>";
    echo "<script> var method = 'text'</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with the following simple code in javascript:

```
if(document.getElementById("type").tagName == "SELECT") {
   //Your code for admin
}
else
{
   //Your code if it is not admin
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have the text or the value with a simple and elegant ternary condition :

```
var result = $("#type").val() !== undefined ? $("#type").val() : $("#type").text();
```